# Load dependent checkboxes on selecting a checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

```
$('#Container').append('<input type="checkbox" id = '+ data[i].name + '/> ' + data[i].name + '<br />');
```

The above code displays a few checkboxes in box A (a div). If I select a checkbox in box A, I send that value to a database and it fetches a values that will be displayed in box B.

For example, if I select 2 checkboxes in Box A, I will send those values to the database and it will fetch corresponding values and display them in box B.

```
 $('#checkbox').change(function() {
```

I would like to know what this `#checkbox`  refers to. Is it the id of checkbox or something else?

Is there any way to implement this?

Comment: `#checkbox` refer's to the element with ID checkbox

Answer (score 1):

yes it is an id..

```
$('#checkbox') <-- refers to an element  having an id as "checkbox" it might be div or checkbox or any element whose id is equal to checkbox. 
$('.checkbox')  <--refers to an element  having class as "checkbox"
$('input:checkbox') <--- refers to all input with type checkbox
```

go through the docs to learn more about [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

**updated**

example

```
$('#Container').append('<input type="checkbox" class="ckbox" id = '+ data[i].name + '/> ' + data[i].name + '<br />');
$('#Container').append('<input type="checkbox" class="ckbox" id = '+ data[i].name + '/> ' + data[i].name + '<br />');
```

call class selector

```
$('#Container').on('change','.ckbox',function(){
    var  selectedValue = $("input.ckbox:checked").map(function(n){
        return this.value;
    });
   alert(seletedValue.join(','));
});
```

`on()` because the check is dynamically added  so have to delegate the event for change event to occur.

Comment: I have data[i].name as id which means i l b getting many ids.how to give change function for this ?

Comment: @sahana first make sure all you ids is unique..and if it is...thn you can name all the checkbox with a class(same) and call class selector for the change event..updated my answer.. check it out

Comment: yeah i got ur point. i just want to collect the checked values.(also unchecked values) as list and send the list to this change function. The place where I create checkboxes is a separate method. This on change should be separate.

Comment: could you please tell me what that function(n) is ? whether it is a separate method to be called?

Comment: i am using a jquery.map to get all the checkbox that is checked.... so that i don't have to use loop to get all the check value..http://api.jquery.com/map/

Comment: i get nothing in the alert !!

Comment: alert value should be selectedValue. I tired with proper value too. But still its empty

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27947/discussion-between-sahana-and-bipen)